# How do I un-collapse the terminal tabs?

Tags: terminal

How do I un-collapse the terminal tabs to be shown side-by-side?
I think I am using CentOS. Do I need share any other info?
[image]
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your question and tell us what desktop environment you use. I think that is xfce, but I haven't used it in years so I'm not sure.